# SharpDXException at SharpDX.dll in 3.0.0

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and my GPU supports DirectX11.

I was using SharpDX for a long time in 2.6.3 version.

When I'm updating to any newer version my code and any code from examples is throwing SharpDXException:

"Additional information: HRESULT: [0x887A0001], Module: [SharpDX.DXGI], ApiCode: [DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL/InvalidCall], Message: Unknown"  while creating device.

In older versions everything is going fine, but I want to use the newest version so I really want to solve this.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

SharpDX 3.0+ made some breaking changes. What you see is the standard error you get when debugging is disabled for the DirectX layer. To get more info, follow [these steps](http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/10/25/Capture-DirectX-1011-debug-output-to-Visual-Studio.aspx). That way, you'll get error details in the Output Window.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a few things you can do going forward.

On your device creation.  Add the following flag.

```
creationFlags |= DeviceCreationFlags.Debug;
```

You can then query the device for the debug interface.  You can also set Directx to error on warnings or even information events.

I will post the exact C# code later if interested. But always leave Debug mode on when in debug (turn off for release).  This will help track the errors more readily.